# Is Python multiprocessing.Queue thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a program which uses both, threads and processes. To share a data between them, I currently use a `multiprocessing.Queue`. Is this queue implementation thread safe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**, it is. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes:

> Queues are thread and process safe.